# How would I limit upload and download speed from the server in golang?

Tags: file-upload, go, download, limit

How would I limit upload and download speed from the server in golang?

I'm writing a golang server to allow users to upload and download files. And file is big, about 1GB bytes. I want to limit the upload and download speed to (for instance) 1MB/s (configurable of course).

below is my upload code:

```
func uploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    file, _, err := r.FormFile("file")

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    defer file.Close()

    os.MkdirAll(`e:\test`, os.ModePerm)
    out, err := os.Create(`e:\test\test.mpg`)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    defer out.Close()

    _, err = io.Copy(out, file)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's a [token bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) algorithm that can be helpful to implement such the rate limit. I found an example implementation, which you can use: https://github.com/juju/ratelimit

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "time"

    "github.com/juju/ratelimit"
)

func main() {
    // Source holding 1MB
    src := bytes.NewReader(make([]byte, 1024*1024))
    // Destination
    dst := &bytes.Buffer{}

    // Bucket adding 100KB every second, holding max 100KB
    bucket := ratelimit.NewBucketWithRate(100*1024, 100*1024)

    start := time.Now()

    // Copy source to destination, but wrap our reader with rate limited one
    io.Copy(dst, ratelimit.Reader(src, bucket))

    fmt.Printf("Copied %d bytes in %s\n", dst.Len(), time.Since(start))
}
```

After running it, the output is:

```
Copied 1048576 bytes in 9.239607694s
```

You can use different bucket implementations to provide desired behaviour. In your code, after setting up right token bucket, you would call:

```
_, err = io.Copy(out, ratelimit.Reader(file, bucket))
```

Comment: This can limit file write speed,but I saw form task manager the network keep high speed.I want to limit network data transfer speed.thanks anyway

Comment: It's my problem.I should use r.MultipartReader() and reader.NextPart() instead of r.FromFile(),because r.FromFile() will saved data in a system temporary file.Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You could check out the implementation of [`PuerkitoBio/throttled`](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/throttled), presented [in this article](http://0value.com/throttled--guardian-of-the-web-server):

> **`throttled`**, a Go package that implements various strategies to control access to HTTP handlers.
>   Out-of-the-box, it supports **rate-limiting of requests**, constant interval flow of requests and memory usage thresholds to grant or deny access, but it also provides mechanisms to extend its functionality.

The rate limit isn't exactly what you need, but can give a good idea for [implementing a similar feature](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/throttled/blob/65b17baf7dd2924b3085f66e4f5677e21cf76c06/throttler.go#L40-L69).

Comment: it seems like throttled drops packages instead of slowdown the transfer... or I'm missing some point?

Comment: @Eric2201 Six years later, I am not too sure. It was useful at the time though.

Comment: @Eric2201 But yes: https://github.com/throttled/throttled/blob/e163db2386224d2c6885508e49b81f93029aa8bd/rate.go#L29-L53. I can see this is less about speed and more about limiting requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/ConduitIO/bwlimit to limit the bandwidth of requests on the server and the client. It differs from other libraries, because it respects read/write deadlines (timeouts) and limits the bandwidth of the whole request including headers, not only the request body.

If you are interested in only limiting the upload and download speed of the file for a single HTTP handler, you can use the `Reader` and `Writer` objects provided by the library.

```golang
package example

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/conduitio/bwlimit"
)

const (
    writeLimit = 1 * bwlimit.Mebibyte // write limit is 1048576 B/s
    readLimit  = 4 * bwlimit.KB       // read limit is 4000 B/s
)

func uploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    file, _, _ := r.FormFile("file")

    // apply bandwidth limit
    fileReader := bwlimit.NewReader(file, readLimit)

    // prepare out ...

    // copy using the bandwidth limit
    _, _ = io.Copy(out, fileReader)
}

func downloadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // prepare file ...
    in, _ := os.Open("file")

    // apply bandwidth limit
    responseWriter := bwlimit.NewWriter(w, writeLimit)

    // write body with bandwidth limit
    io.Copy(responseWriter, in)
}
```